# Use of subjunctive

Tags: grammar, subjunctive-mood

Could you please help me understand why Simpson, in his *Stylistics*, uses subjunctive mood in the sentence below:

"The second problem is about what would hapen should a phrase that did contain adjectives suddenly **appear** in the text."

Sorry if you find the answer to this question too obvious

Comment: "The second problem is about what would happen **if** a phrase (that did contain adjectives) **should** suddenly **appear** in the text."

Comment: That's not a subjunctive construction. "Appear" is in the plain (infinitive) form because it follows the modal verb "should".

Comment: Yeah, I agree with @Rathony. In fact, I insist the word's placement be changed. [Hey, I just found another use for the subjunctive: when something is mandatory, as when "I insist . . .]. We also know the subjunctive mood (or mode) can be used when talking  about hypothetical situations; you know, "What if I were [not "was"] to punch you in the nose?" I'm not going to, of course, but we can pretend I do and then you pretend you've been punched in the nose by me and imagine how it feels, how you react, what you say when it happens, and so on.

Comment: @rhetorician Yes, but "appear" in the OP's example is not subjunctive. Btw, "were" is the "irrealis" mood, not subjunctive.

Comment: @BillJ: I'll have to defer to you in this. Maybe I should stick to rhetorical matters and leave the grammatical matters to others!? Don

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement can be rephrased as: The second problem is about what would happen *if* a phrase that contained adjectives suddenly *appeared* in the text. 
In this instance, it can be clearly seen that the statement pertains to a contingent or hypothetical situation. Note that in this rephrasing, in the subordinate clause beginning with *if*, the following verb will be in the simple past tense.